# How to install specific JDK (jdk1.8.0_152.jdk) on MacOS?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8

For the life of me I can't figure this out.

IntelliJ is supposed to be bundled with this version I thought but it doesn't appear in my `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`.

I used `brew` to install the current version of java8 which is `jdk1.8.0_202.jdk` but that isn't what our production servers are using and it actually has some features that get in my way right now.

Oracle only gives the ability to download `jdk1.8.0_211.jdk` or `jdk1.8.0_212.jdk` and I don't see a feature to look at historical versions.

I'm fairly sure this is a redundant question and I apologize for that but I can't seem to find it anywhere despite searching for a couple of hours at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle provides an archive of [every](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html) version of Java. If you're specifically looking for a sub-version of [Java 8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), they have that, too.

Comment: I... don't know how I couldn't find this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to install, remove, and switch between different JDKs on MacOS is with [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/). Currently, the following JDK versions are supported:

```
$ sdk l java
================================================================================
Available Java Versions
================================================================================
     13.ea.19-open       10.0.2-zulu       * 7.0.181-zulu                       
     12.0.1-sapmchn      10.0.2-open         1.0.0-rc-16-grl                    
     12.0.1-zulu         9.0.7-zulu          1.0.0-rc-15-grl                    
     12.0.1-open         9.0.4-open          1.0.0-rc-14-grl                    
     12.0.1.j9-adpt    + 8u152-zulu                                             
     12.0.1.hs-adpt      8.0.212-zulu                                           
     12.0.1-librca       8.0.212-amzn                                           
     11.0.3-sapmchn      8.0.212.j9-adpt                                        
     11.0.3-zulu         8.0.212.hs-adpt                                        
     11.0.3-amzn         8.0.212-librca                                         
     11.0.3.j9-adpt      8.0.202-zulu                                           
     11.0.3.hs-adpt      8.0.202-amzn                                           
     11.0.3-librca       8.0.202-zulufx                                         
     11.0.2-open     > + 8.0.201-oracle                                         
     11.0.2-zulufx       7.0.222-zulu                                           

================================================================================
+ - local version
* - installed
> - currently in use
================================================================================
```

SDKMAN can also be used to install other JVM-based tools, languages, and frameworks such as Groovy, Grails, Ant, Gradle, Kotlin, Maven, Scala.